# template specialization sub class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, inheritance

I have a problem that can be minimized to the following example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


class A{
  public:
    const char* chr;
    A(){chr = "aaa";}
};

class B : A{
  public:
    const char* chr;
    B(){chr = "bbb";}
};

template <class T>
std::string to_str(T) = delete;

template<>
inline std::string
to_str<A>(A object) {
    std::string str;
    return str.assign((object.chr));
}

int main() {
  A a;
  B b;
  std::cout << to_str(b) << std::endl;
}
```

when changing it to `std::cout << to_str(a) << std::endl;` the code runs and prints '`aaa`', but like this, it stops at compilation and outputs

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:30:24: error: use of deleted function 'std::__cxx11::string to_str(T) [with T = B; std::__cxx11::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]'
   std::cout << to_str(b) << std::endl;
                        ^
main.cpp:18:13: note: declared here
 std::string to_str(T) = delete;
             ^~~~~~

exit status 1
```

now lets say i have a lot of classes that inherit `A`, can i 'tell' the compiler they all can go to the same function (the one accepts `A`)?

Thanks.

Comment: Java does *not* have templates. Trying to find similarities between generics and templates beyond a bit of syntax is a recipe for confusion.

Comment: Do you really need a template? If not, then you only need 1 regular function that take `A` by (const) reference...

Comment: @DsCpp: Does it *have* to be a `const char*` in the classes?

Comment: @DsCpp: Do you have control over the specializations written for `to_str`?

Comment: Does `B` have to have a member that hides the identically typed member in `A`? And which do you want to refer to in `to_string`?

Answer (score 5):

> can i 'tell' the compiler they all can go to the same function(the one accepts A)?

Yes, using SFINAE and `std::is_base_of`

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<A, T>::value, std::string>::type
      to_str (T const & t)
 { return t.chr; }
```

The following is a full working example

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct A     { char const * chr; A() : chr{"aaa"} {} };
struct B : A { char const * chr; B() : chr{"bbb"} {} };
struct C     { char const * chr; C() : chr{"ccc"} {} };    

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<A, T>::value, std::string>::type
      to_str (T const & t)
 { return t.chr; }

int main()
 {
   A a;
   B b;
   C c;

   std::cout << to_str(a) << std::endl;    // print aaa
   std::cout << to_str(b) << std::endl;    // print bbb
   // std::cout << to_str(c) << std::endl; // compilation error
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I question if this really is a minimized example of your problem. I think that what's happened is that some important details got lost in the translation, because the code you've shown us here has a number of issues.

1. `B` inherits privately from `A`. There is no way we can really treat a `B` like an `A` in this case.

If you changed inheritance to `public`, then we could attempt to force a `B` in like so:

```
class B : public A{/*...*/};
// ...
std::cout << to_str(*static_cast<A*>(&b)) << std::endl;
```

But the output will remain "aaa", which leads me to my next points

2. Your `to_str` specialization for `A` accepts by *value*. This is important because even if we wanted to force a `B` in, we end up *slicing* the object, this matters because
3. `B` redefines the `const char* chr` effectively *hiding* `A::chr`, and since we've sliced, there's no way to recover `B`'s `chr`.

We could start fixing things but first fixing the *slicing* by accepting `A` by *reference* instead (or `const` reference), and *always* preferring an overload instead of a template specialization for a function:

```
std::string to_str(A& object) {/*...*/}
```

4. The next problem is that there is no way direct to recover `B`'s `chr` from an instance of `A`. We could go one of two ways here.

   1. Use a `std::string` member in `A` and *do not redeclare it in any derived class*, then derived classes can set it on initialization.

Example:

```
class A{
  public:
    std::string chr;
    A():chr{"aaa"}{}
};

class B : public A{
  public:
    B(){chr = "bbb";}
};
```

2. We write a `virtual const char* get_char()` method in `A` that derived classes can override.

Example:

```
class A{
  public:
    const char* chr;
    A(){chr = "aaa";}
    virtual const char* get_chr() const{return chr;}
};

class B : public A{
  public:
    const char* chr;
    B(){chr = "bbb";}
    const char* get_chr() const override {return chr;}
};

template <class T>
std::string to_str(T) = delete;

std::string to_str(A& object) {
    std::string str;
    return str.assign((object.get_chr()));
// ...
std::cout << to_str(*static_cast<A*>(&b)) << std::endl;
```

Note that at this point we're still forcing each `B` to be an `A`, which leads me to my next point

5. `template <class T> std::string to_str(T) = delete;` will always exactly match every type you don't explicitly specialize for, being preferred in the worst case and causing ambiguity in the best case.

   If you don't have any control over this function, then we're stuck with what we've got. However, if we *do*, then we can achieve what we need using `type_traits` to accept anything that is derived from `A`.

In this way we can keep your private inheritance, and also keep your redeclared `chr` member, while simultaneously disabling `to_str` for everything else *and* not requiring we `static_cast` our `b`.

Example:

```
#include <type_traits>

class A{
  public:
    const char* chr;
    A(){chr = "aaa";}
};

class B : A{
  public:
    const char* chr;
    B(){chr = "bbb";}
};

template<class T, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<A, T>::value, int>>
inline std::string to_str(T& object) {
    std::string str;
    return str.assign((object.chr));
}

int main() {
  A a;
  B b;
  std::cout << to_str(b) << std::endl;
}
```

Overall, I think that the best approach would be to give `A` a `protected std::string chr` that each derived class sets on initialization, and then have your `to_string` function that is specialized for `A&` (as an **overload**) print that member.

---

Edit: I forgot one last note. Issue #6: There are no `virtual` members in `A`. Therefore you will never be able to `dynamic_cast` a pointer to `A` to any derived class.

Answer (score 1):

Template function specialization does not work that way.  There is no overload resolution; it merely permits replacing a specific function body with specific template arguments with your specialized one.  It is rarely useful.

What you want is overload resolution, possibly with tag dispatch.

First remove this completely:

```
template <class T>
std::string to_str(T) = delete;
```

next, write an overload:

```
inline std::string to_str(A object) {
  std::string str;
  return str.assign((object.chr));
}
```

and done.  Overload resolution dispatches `B` to the `A` overload.

Your next problem is slicing.  `B` has *two* members named `chr`:  `A::chr` and `B::chr`.  For no good reason.  In addition you are needlessly copying `A` (or the `A` subobject of `B`).

```
inline std::string to_str(A const& object) {
  std::string str;
  return str.assign((object.chr));
}
```

this avoids a needless copy of `A`.

```
class A{
  public:
    const char* chr;
    A(){chr = "aaa";}
};

class B : public A{ // public, not private
  public:
    // const char* chr; // no need for this
    B(){chr = "bbb";}
};
```

Comment: I have a sense of [deja vu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39250545/sfinae-to-make-base-template-always-result-in-error) :)

Comment: Well, there's still slicing to worry about. Which matters because `B` redeclares `chr`

Answer (score -3):

> According to 14.7.3 [temp.expl.spec] paragraph 1, only non-deleted function templates may be explicitly specialized

[C++ Standard Core Language Defect Reports and Accepted Issues, Revision 97](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#941)

So, if you change

```
template <class T>
std::string to_str(T) = delete;
```

in, for example,

```
template <class T>
std::string to_str(T) { return ""; }
```

everything should work

Comment: The defect report you quoted (that was also voted *in*) proposes to allow the specialization. [And the wording in the standard now reflects that](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.expl.spec#1).

Comment: This is both wrong and wrong.  The DR **permits** specializing deleted function templates, and your change fails to fix the OP's problem.  The link is interesting if not useful; the rest of the answer has negative value.